# Creating a new Object with Javascript to re-use code

Tags: javascript

I am trying to re-use the object  "tips", below is the code for creating the object

```
class tipArray extends Array{

    sum() {

        return this.reduce((sum,current) => sum + current)
    }
}

var tips = {
    bills: new tipArray(),
    newTip: function(){
        bills: new tipArray();
    },
    addTip: function(val){
        this.bills.push(val)
    },
    getTip: function(bills)  {
        for(i = 0;i <= this.bills.length - 1; i++)   {
            if(this.bills[i]<50){
                this.tipval= this.bills[i] * 0.2
                console.log(this.tipval)
            }
            else if(this.bills[i]>= 50 && this.bills[i] < 200){
                this.tipval = this.bills[i] * 0.15
                console.log(this.tipval)
            }
            else if(this.bills[i]>= 200){
                this.tipval= this.bills[i] * 0.1
                console.log(this.tipval)
            }
        }
    },
    getAvg: function(){
        this.avgVal = this.bills.sum()/(this.bills.length);
        return this.avgVal;
    },
    getSum: function() {
        return this.bills.sum();
    }
}
```

Then I run the following code to find the output

```
var fam1 = tips;
fam1.addTip(10);
fam1.addTip(50);
fam1.getTip();

output = 2, 4
```

When I try to create a new object

```
var fam2 = tips;
fam2.addTip(30);
fam2.addTip(80);
fam2.getTip();

expected output = 6, 12
output = 2,4,6,12
```

How can i re-initialize the object and have the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not take a class and short `getTip` a bit by using the early return paradigm.

```js
class tipArray extends Array{
    sum() { return this.reduce((sum,current) => sum + current); }
}

class Tips {
    constructor () {
        this.bills = new tipArray();
    }
    
    newTip() {
        this.bills = new tipArray();
    }
    
    addTip(val) {
        this.bills.push(val);
    }
    
    getTip() {
        return this.bills.map(val => {
            if (val < 50) {
                return val * 0.2;
            }
            if (val < 200) {
                return val * 0.15;
            }
            return val * 0.1;
        });
    }
    
    getAvg () {
        this.avgVal = this.bills.sum() / this.bills.length;
        return this.avgVal;
    }
    
    getSum () {
        return this.bills.sum();
    }
}

var fam1 = new Tips;
fam1.addTip(10);
fam1.addTip(50);
console.log(fam1.getTip());

var fam2 = new Tips;
fam2.addTip(30);
fam2.addTip(80);
console.log(fam2.getTip());
```

Comment: Although some of the other answers did the job..i really like the use of classes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably to use a function to create a "virgin" copy of the object each time:

```
function newTips() {
    var tips = {
        bills: new tipArray(),
        newTip: function(){
            bills: new tipArray();
        },
        addTip: function(val){
            this.bills.push(val)
        },
        getTip: function(bills)  {
            for(i = 0;i <= this.bills.length - 1; i++)   {
                if(this.bills[i]<50){
                    this.tipval= this.bills[i] * 0.2
                    console.log(this.tipval)
                }
                else if(this.bills[i]>= 50 && this.bills[i] < 200){
                    this.tipval = this.bills[i] * 0.15
                    console.log(this.tipval)
                }
                else if(this.bills[i]>= 200){
                    this.tipval= this.bills[i] * 0.1
                    console.log(this.tipval)
                }
            }
        },
        getAvg: function(){
            this.avgVal = this.bills.sum()/(this.bills.length);
            return this.avgVal;
        },
        getSum: function() {
            return this.bills.sum();
        }
    }
    return tips;
}

var tip1 = newTips();
// perform operations on tip1;

var tip2 = newTips();
// should be a "fresh" copy
```

Answer (score 0):

easy way out is to makes tips a function and return the object from it

```
var tips = () => ({
    bills: new tipArray(),
    newTip: function(){
        bills: new tipArray();
    },
    addTip: function(val){
        this.bills.push(val)
    },
    getTip: function(bills)  {
        for(i = 0;i <= this.bills.length - 1; i++)   {
            if(this.bills[i]<50){
                this.tipval= this.bills[i] * 0.2
                console.log(this.tipval)
            }
            else if(this.bills[i]>= 50 && this.bills[i] < 200){
                this.tipval = this.bills[i] * 0.15
                console.log(this.tipval)
            }
            else if(this.bills[i]>= 200){
                this.tipval= this.bills[i] * 0.1
                console.log(this.tipval)
            }
        }
    },
    getAvg: function(){
        this.avgVal = this.bills.sum()/(this.bills.length);
        return this.avgVal;
    },
    getSum: function() {
        return this.bills.sum();
    }
})

var fam1 = tips();
fam1.addTip(10);
fam1.addTip(50);
fam1.getTip();

var fam2 = tips();
fam2.addTip(30);
fam2.addTip(80);
fam2.getTip();
```

but i think you should extract this tips functionality into a separate class like tipCalculator

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you only copy the reference to the object.

```
var fam1 = tips;
```

What you need, is a new instance with fresh values.

I think the easiest way is to create a function, that returns your current object.

```
class tipArray extends Array{
    sum() {
        return this.reduce((sum,current) => sum + current)
    }
}

function tips(){
    return {
        bills: new tipArray(),
        newTip: function(){
            bills: new tipArray();
        },
        addTip: function(val){
            this.bills.push(val)
        },
        getTip: function(bills)  {
            for(i = 0;i <= this.bills.length - 1; i++)   {
                if(this.bills[i]<50){
                    this.tipval= this.bills[i] * 0.2
                    console.log(this.tipval)
                }
                else if(this.bills[i]>= 50 && this.bills[i] < 200){
                    this.tipval = this.bills[i] * 0.15
                    console.log(this.tipval)
                }
                else if(this.bills[i]>= 200){
                    this.tipval= this.bills[i] * 0.1
                    console.log(this.tipval)
                }
            }
        },
        getAvg: function(){
            this.avgVal = this.bills.sum()/(this.bills.length);
            return this.avgVal;
        },
        getSum: function() {
            return this.bills.sum();
        }
    }
}
console.log("-FIRST-");
var fam1 = tips();
fam1.addTip(10);
fam1.addTip(50);
fam1.getTip();

console.log("-Second-");
var fam2 = tips();
fam2.addTip(30);
fam2.addTip(80);
fam2.getTip();
```

Answer (score 0):

Little bit clear by Object.create

```js
class tipArray extends Array {
  sum() {
    return this.reduce((sum, current) => sum + current)
  }
}


const tips = {
  init() { 
    this.bills = new tipArray();  
    return this;
  },
  newTip() {
    this.bills = new tipArray();
  },
  addTip(val) {
    this.bills.push(val);
  },
  getTip() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.bills.length - 1; i++) {
      if (this.bills[i] < 50) {
        this.tipval = this.bills[i] * 0.2
        console.log(this.tipval)
      } else if (this.bills[i] >= 50 && this.bills[i] < 200) {
        this.tipval = this.bills[i] * 0.15
        console.log(this.tipval)
      } else if (this.bills[i] >= 200) {
        this.tipval = this.bills[i] * 0.1
        console.log(this.tipval)
      }
    }
  },
  
  getAvg() {
    this.avgVal = this.bills.sum() / (this.bills.length);
    return this.avgVal;
  },
  
  getSum() {
    return this.bills.sum();
  }
}

const fam1 = Object.create(tips).init();
fam1.addTip(10);
fam1.addTip(50);
console.log('fam1',fam1.getSum());

const fam2 = Object.create(tips).init();
fam2.addTip(20);
fam2.addTip(70);
console.log('fam2',fam2.getSum());
```